# How to copy file from one stage to another stage in azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I've multi-stage azure build pipeline for my application, In the first stage, I'm building the source code and executing **`test.sh`** - this shell script create a new shell script file called **`data.sh`**. In my second stage, I'm executing **`run.sh`** which execute this newly created file **`data.sh`** but I'm getting **`No such file or directory error`** and my pipeline failed in the second stage.

The newly created file **data.sh** is not copied from my previous stage, how can I get **`data.sh`** into my second stage, please find my code below:

Much appreciated if you someone could help me to resolve this issue, I need `data.sh` file in my `stage 2` which got created in `stage 1`

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
  - none

pool:
 vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: TestFilecopy
    displayName: Extecute test script 
    jobs:
      - job: myJob1
        displayName: Execute myJob1
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: filePath
            filePath: 'myApp/test.sh'
            workingDirectory: myApp

  - stage: TestFilecopy1
    displayName: Extecute new script 
    jobs:
      - job: myJob2
        displayName: Execute myJob2
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: filePath
            filePath: 'myApp/run.sh'
            workingDirectory: myApp
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello word"
echo $PWD
ls -la

echo "#!/bin/bash
      echo 'Hello World'" > data.sh

ls -la
```

**run.sh**

```
echo "hello run file"
echo $PWD
ls -la
./data.sh
```

**Folder Structure**

```
product-pipeline-project/
├─ myApp/
│  ├─ run.sh
│  ├─ test.sh
├─ azure-pipeline.yml
```

**Pipeline console output**
**Stage 1 Output Log**

```
Generating script.
Formatted command: exec bash '/home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp/test.sh'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/ef037ffc-0ea8-4366-b074-10120c9b1434.sh
hello word
/home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker   48 Jul 11 18:25 run.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker  109 Jul 11 18:25 test.sh
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker   37 Jul 11 18:25 data.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker   48 Jul 11 18:25 run.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker  109 Jul 11 18:25 test.sh
```

**Stage 2 Output Log**

```
Generating script.
Formatted command: exec bash '/home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp/run.sh'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/087e12fd-0b7b-4bd5-a4a8-7b7879255f3f.sh
hello run file
/home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 vsts docker 4096 Jul 11 18:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker   48 Jul 11 18:25 run.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker  109 Jul 11 18:25 test.sh
/home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp/run.sh: line 4: ./data.sh: No such file or directory
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
Finishing: Bash
```

Answer (score 3):

Each job runs on separate machine. Thus file generate in one job is not accessible in another job. To make it available you need to publish as artifact and then download it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have doc for that.

In your case it would be:

```
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/product-pipeline-project/myApp/data.sh
  artifact: WebApp
```

and then on another stage:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifact: 'WebApp'
    path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/product-pipeline-project/myApp
```

But consider if you really need a sperate stage for that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Krzysztof Madej. I'm having some sensitive PII data in my 'data.sh' file so publishing artifact is not a good option for my use case. i think - please suggest if any alterative option if you could think of. Thanks once again!

Comment: Well if you don't want to persisit this file please consider run in one single job. Why do you need seprate stages and jobs?